# App Rejected: Crashed on iPad 2.10. Cannot Replicate Error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, crash, crash-reports

recently my app got rejected by Apple stating a non-compliance to 2.10 of the apple guidelines.

----- 2.10 -----

We found that your app crashed on iPad, which doesn't meet the requirements for running on iPad, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Apple has sent me the crash logs for the app but I have no idea how to interpret them. The crash log is as such:

EDIT:

I have managed to symbolicate the crash log, here it is:

[The Symbolicated Crash Log](http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah58/Wesley_Ow/symbolicatedCrashLog_zpscd13eb6a.png)

here's the source code to the specific function causing the error:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if let numberOfFetchedObjects = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count {
            return numberOfFetchedObjects

        }

    else {return 0}
}
```

heres the rest of the code on the view controller related to the tableView and the fetchedResultsController:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    setupFetchedResultsControllerAndDelegate()
    fetchResults()


    self.adBanner.delegate = self

    self.goalTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
    self.goalTableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(90.0)



    //check if theres a local notification payload
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as AppDelegate

    if let notification = appDelegate.localNotificationToPass {
        self.performFollowUpActionForNotification(notification)
        appDelegate.localNotificationToPass = nil
    }


    //check if theres a need to present rate app alert
    if appDelegate.goalPageShouldShowAlert == true {
        self.showRateAppAlert()
    }

}

//MARK: - Fetched Results Controller Set Up & Helper Methods

func setupFetchedResultsControllerAndDelegate() {


    //initialize fetch request
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Goal")

    //initialize predicate
    let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"isDone == %@", false)!
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    //set sort descriptor
    let sortDescriptor:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateCreated", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    //set up fetched results controller variable
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
}

func fetchResults() {
    var error = NSErrorPointer()

    if !fetchedResultsController.performFetch(error) {
        //MARK: replace the print line function below to an alert for consumers later on
        println("Could not fetch results \n with error: \(error)")
    }
}



 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:GoalCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("goalCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as GoalCell
    configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath, forViewController: self)

    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell:GoalCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, forViewController viewController:UIViewController){

    var fetchedGoals = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as [Goal]

    let cellGoal = fetchedGoals[indexPath.row]


    cell.goalNameLabel.text = cellGoal.name

    cell.goalDatelineLabel.text = Goal.convertGoalDueDateToString(cellGoal)

    cell.parentViewController = self

    cell.clipsToBounds = true





}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        let goal:Goal = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects![indexPath.row] as Goal
        self.context.deleteObject(goal)
        self.cancelNotificationForGoal(goal)

        var error = NSErrorPointer()
        self.context.save(error)
    }


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if self.goalTableView.editing == true {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addOrEditGoal", sender: self)
    }


    else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showGoalDetailView", sender: self)
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.setEditingForVC()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if self.goalTableView.editing == false {
        self.changeDoneButtonToEdit()
    }
}

//MARK: - Fetched Results Controller Delegate Protocol Methods
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.goalTableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.showOrHideEmptyTableViewLabel()
    self.goalTableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert :
        self.goalTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete :
        self.goalTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        self.configureCell((self.goalTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as GoalCell), atIndexPath: indexPath!, forViewController: self)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:

        self.goalTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        self.goalTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)

    }
}


 //MARK: - ADBannerViewDelegate

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    //if will leave is true, it means the ad might take the user to another app or window.
    if willLeave == true {
        let error = NSErrorPointer()
        self.context.save(error)

        return true
    }

    else {return true}
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {

    banner.hidden = true
    self.tableViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0

    self.goalTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

    banner.hidden = false
    self.tableViewBottomConstraint.constant = banner.frame.height
    self.goalTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report and see where the assertion in your code is thrown.

Comment: Did your app have something like delete table cell or change order of cell ? in any view.

Comment: @Kerni okay ill get to it

Comment: @Jageen yes the tableView allows for deletion

Comment: @WesleyOw i have strong felling that the problem is on that screen , do testing on that screen, like having single cell and perform deleting. (In my case there was a problem like when i delete cell it will select another cell and perform something and app crash) .

Comment: @Jageen the weird thing is when i test the app on an iPad simulator, all its functions work exactly as it should. no crashes reported. I haven't been able to replicate any crash on the simulator as of yet so my options are to examine the crash log for an idea of what happened or test it on an iPad and try to replicate the crash

Comment: @WesleyOw try to test on devices because some times applicaiton crash because of memory warning or others things, it depends on iOS version also. i suggest to test with device in iOS7 and iOS8 both.

Comment: @Jageen alright i will. It's really strange that I have to test an iPhone only app on an iPad as well. oh well

Comment: @Kerni I have symbolicated the crash log, what do you guys think the error is now? I definitely know its stemming from the table view but what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Without the referenced source code, not much can be said. Please add that to your question. (including which lines are the ones referenced in the stack trace)

Comment: @Kerni added the related source code